# reference variables from pom.xml to deployment.yaml

Tags: java, kubernetes, pom.xml

i want to use maven pom.xml variables in a kubernetes deployment.yaml file. the variables i want to reference are ${project.artifactId} and ${project.version} which is pulled from

```html
pom.xml

<groupId>my-project</groupId>
<artifactId>>my-project</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

and this is what i want to achieve

```js
deploment.yaml


apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: my-project
      image: ${project.artifactId}:${project.version}
```

with this attempt i get an ***InvalidImageName*** error.
[image]

please advice on which better way of doing this.

Comment: Maven and Kubernetes are unrelated technologies. Please edit your question to show the program you are running to adapt Maven to Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

I would say its issue with your deploment.yaml content. 
I have use it (with nginx image) on K8s and get error below:

```
error: error when retrieving current configuration of:
Resource: "/v1, Resource=pods", GroupVersionKind: "/v1, Kind=Pod"
Name: "", Namespace: "default"
Object: &{map["apiVersion":"v1" "kind":"Pod" "spec":map["containers":[map["name":"test" "image":"nginx"]]] "metadata":map["namespace":"default" "annotations":map["kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""]]]}
from server for: "pod.yaml": resource name may not be empty
```

In your current file you have named only `container`. You have to specify your `POD` name using `metadata.name`. In metadata section you can also specify `namespace`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
```

In addition keep in mind that `kind: Pod` and `kind: Deployment` are two different things (bit confused regarding your YAML file name).